# How to code a parameter with a variable that expands into a variable number of parameter components

Tags: bash, parameters, expansion

This is a very basic question about parameter expansion. By way of example, here are two forms of the audio codec parameter for the ffmpeg command:

Form 1:

```
ffmpeg ... -acodec copy ...
```

Form 2:

```
ffmpeg ... -an ...
```

I would like to express the parameter and (for form 1) its value as a variable or variables that would work in both scenarios.

This works for form 1:

```
param1="-acodec"
param2="copy"
ffmpeg ... "$param1" "$param2" ...
```

but this doesn't work:

```
param="-acodec copy"
ffmpeg ... "$param" ...
```

nor does this work:

```
param1="-acodec"
param2=" copy"
ffmpeg ... "$param1$param2"
```

Conversely, this works for form 2:

```
param="-an"
ffmpeg ... "$param" ...
```

and this works:

```
param1="-an"
param2=""
ffmpeg ... "$param1$param2"
```

but this obviously doesn't work because of the extra space character:

```
param1="-an"
param2=""
ffmpeg ... "$param1" "$param2" ...
```

Is there a single expression that works for both forms of the parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an array.

```
# Pick one.
# param=(-acodec copy)
# param=(-an)

ffmpeg ... "${param[@]}" ...
```

Comment: This works perfectly in my initial testing. Thank you!

Comment: For other newbies like myself, I found that I can add further parameters as follows (continuing with the current ffmpeg example): param+=(-vcodec libx264); param+=(-ar 48000); etc. The single expression "${param[@]}" will expand all the parameters appropriately. Thank you again for the very helpful tip, chepner.